# How to avoid PowerShell command unrecognized term error

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to run the command below to find the user session ID of a user and print it, and the command is the following:

```
$uid = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -filter {$_.UserName -eq 'pedro.vieira'} | select -ExpandProperty UnifiedSessionID; $uid
```

If I open powershell as Administrator, runs exactly as intended, yet if I open powershell without admin permissions, I get an error saying I should be in an elevated mode, which is expect.

However, for a specific motive, I want exactly for that to happen, so I'm trying the same command but prefixing it with `Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -Verb RunAs powershell`, like this:

```
Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -Verb RunAs powershell "$uid = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -filter {$_.UserName -eq 'pedro.vieira'} | select -ExpandProperty UnifiedSessionID; $uid; Start-Sleep -Seconds 5"
```

Yet I get an error stating:

```
=: The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
```

I've tried escaping the dollar sign before the variable assignment but then I get an error stating that now the `\` character is the one not recognized.

When I try a simpler command without variables, like the one below it works perfectly:

```
Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -Verb RunAs powershell "Get-RDUserSession"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the description to comply with this

Comment: The PSModulePath may be different for an Admin than normal user.  From Start Button Type "Edit Environmental" and see if path is different for Admin than normal user.

Comment: Try to use single quotation marks to avoid string interpolation: `Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -Verb RunAs powershell '$uid = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -filter {$_.UserName -eq ''pedro.vieira''} | select -ExpandProperty UnifiedSessionID; $uid; Start-Sleep -Seconds 5'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Write-Output` with `-OutVariable` to get the username to a string variable. Try something like:

```
Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -Verb RunAs powershell 'Write-Output pedro.vieira -OutVariable user; $uid = Get-RDUserSession | Where-Object -filter {$_.UserName -eq $user} | select -ExpandProperty UnifiedSessionID; $uid; Start-Sleep -Seconds 5'"
```